# scrollOverflow using FullPageJS not working on click event

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, fullpage.js

I'm building a instance of Fullpage.js that has to be initialized on a click event, then destroyed when clicking to another page, and vice versa. scrollOverflow works fine if the the #fullpage element is not hidden on page load.

When .fullpage-trigger is clicked the #fullpage element is displayed and built, but the two elements with the classes .fp-scrollable and .fp-scroller aren't created?

Broken live example: http://realbadrabbits.com/test/bug.html

Thanks in advance :)

```
$('.fullpage-trigger').on('click', function(event) {
    $('#fullpage').fullpage({
        anchors: ['1', '2'],
        navigation: true,
        navigationPosition: 'left',
        navigationTooltips: ['1', '2'],
        scrollOverflow: true
    });
});

$(document).on('click', '.destroy', function(){
    $.fn.fullpage.destroy('all');
    $('#fullpage').removeClass('active');
    $('#fullpage').addClass('hide-page');
});
```

Comment: Working as expected?? I can see the scroll bar as expected.

Comment: Hello @Alvaro :) I re-wrote my question because I think I've narrowed down the bug, it seems to be an issue of building the fullpage element with a click event. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Also, I'm noticed that once fullpage in initialized if I make the browser window smaller it begins to work as expected. I can't make sense of this?

Answer (score 1):

Try using `$.fn.fullpage.reBuild()` after your initialisation. Or in the `afterRender` callback.

Answer (score 0):

```
//forcing fullPage.js to recalculate dimensions.
setTimeout(function(){
  fullpage_api.reBuild(); 
}, 500);
```

this worked for me